# Criteria: How to get childs without parents

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a little problem with Criteria and Hibernate on Netbeans.

The solutions that can serve me are several: using the metamodel in Netbeans (it is the solution to all my problems, but console often spits an error saying that it does not find the source), or the code needed to do the query.

The situation is the following:
I have a parent entity called Grado, and a child entity called Materia. The relationship is one to many. A Grado can have several Materias: English, Mathematics, Physics, Ethics ...

I need to do a query, or several, to get a list of the materias without assigning a parent. The equivalent in SQL that I am trying to get is: `SELECT * FROM Materia where id not in (select id from Materia m join grado_materia g on m.id = g.materias_id);`

**Grado** parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Grado implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Materia> materias;

    //getters and setters
}
```

**Materia** child entity

```
@Entity
public class Materia implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String nombre;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Hibernate generates the following relations
[grado -> grado_materia <- materia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkWiw.png)

**Edit**
To complete the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336171/criteria-how-to-get-childs-without-parents/59336301#59336301) provided by @Spiderman to the problem I had, I put the query for future readers

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = sesion.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Materia> cq = cb.createQuery(Materia.class);
Root<Materia> root = cq.from(Materia.class);
cq.select(root);
cq.where(root.get("grado").isNull());
Query query = sesion.createQuery(cq);
List<Materia> results = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

To Grado model add

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="grado_id")
private List<Materia> materias;
```

And To Materia  Model add

```
@ManyToOne
private Grado grado ;
```

Adding the above to the Materia model will prevent a join table from being created.

Comment: Thank you very much for your early response. I don't know how JoinColumn works until I've been checking the changes I made in the database.
Please, change the following JoinColumn line so that it can be considered valid, as it can lead to mistakes. `@JoinColumn(name = "grado_id")`